# How to display an image from postgrsql database in virtual machine to my local

Tags: php, postgresql, odoo

I'm  trying  to  display  an  image  from  PostgreSQL  database  and  I'm  retrieving  a  black  screen  .  in  the  field  **store_fname**  i'm  having  the  field  will  give  you  the  path  to  the  image  file  inside  my  Odoo 
 filestore  in  the  form  `'ab/abcdef0123456789'`

```
<?php
$conn = pg_connect("user = admin password = admin host = 192.168.1.11 dbname = odoo");
$res = pg_query($conn, "SELECT id, store_fname FROM ir_attachment
WHERE res_model = 'res.partner' AND res_field = 'image' AND res_id = 3; ");
$raw = pg_fetch_result($res, 'store_fname');
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo pg_unescape_bytea($raw);
?>
```

Comment: If you store the file retrieved to disk and open it from there (directly, not via web), is it good then?

Comment: Your description says you stored a path to the image in the database, while your code is expecting the image itself to be in the database.

Comment: instead of `echo pg_unescape_bytea($raw);` you need to retrieve the image content from Odoo filestore and emit that.